# IIS 7.5, ASP.NET, impersonation, and access to C:\Windows\Temp

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, permissions, impersonation

**Summary**: One of our web applications requires write access to `C:\Windows\Temp`. However, no matter how much I weaken the NTFS permission, [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) shows `ACCESS DENIED`.

**Background** (which might or might not be relevant for the problem): We are using OLEDB to access an MS Access database (which is located *outside* of C:\Windows\Temp). Unfortunately, this OLEDB driver requires write access to the user profile's TEMP directory (which happens to be C:\Windows\Temp when running under IIS 7.5), otherwise the dreaded "Unspecified Error" OleDbException is thrown. See [KB 926939](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926939) for details. I followed the steps in the KB article, but it doesn't help.

**Details**:

This is the output of `icacls C:\Windows\Temp`. For debugging purposes I gave full permissions to `Everyone`.

```
C:\Windows\Temp NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(S,RD)
                BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(S,WD,AD,X)
                BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

However, this is the screenshot of procmon:

[image: procmon screenshot]

```
Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Delete
Disposition:    Create
Options:        Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Delete On Close, Open No Recall
Attributes:     NT
ShareMode:      None
AllocationSize: 0
Impersonating:  MYDOMAIN\myuser
```

PS: When logged in as `MYDOMAIN\myuser`, I can create files in `C:\Windows\Temp` using Windows Explorer without any problems.

**EDIT**: Relevant parts of web.config:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
 <identity impersonate="true" />
 <authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
   <allow users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

Authentication seems to work, i.e., `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` (which is shown on my custom error page) returns `MYDOMAIN\myuser`.

Comment: PS: I also considered posting this to serverfault instead, but my guess would be that this is a problem with how ASP.NET handles impersonation rather than a Windows configuration issue.

Comment: What are the values for `<authorization ...>` and `<identity ...>` in `Web.config` and is IIS configured to allow anonymous access (not sure if this is still applicable in IIS7)?

Comment: @scherand: I've updated my question. IIS7.5 seems to use the .net settings w.r.t. anonymous access.

Comment: Hmm - that is beyond me, sorry to have bothered you :( If you feel like experimenting and have not done so already you might check what identity through `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` or `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` and if you feel like reading I found the following article [Breaking Changes for ASP.NET 2.0 applications running in Integrated mode on IIS 7.0](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/12/08/IIS-7.0-Breaking-Changes-ASP.NET-2.0-applications-Integrated-mode.aspx) but I am not at all sure if this is going to help...

Comment: Did you add permission for ServerName\ASPNET as described in KB827190 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827190)?

Comment: @Sheng: Well, I gave full permissions for `Everyone`, which should include `ServerName\ASPNET`, right?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?!

Comment: @SirCrispalot: Well, we "solved" it by replacing the Access database with an XML file. Unfortunately, we never found the underlying cause for the original problem.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried following the steps on this:
[loadUserProfile and IIS 7 temporary directory failures](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx)

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I did (grant permissions). I even went so far as to grant *full* permissions.

Comment: If that's where the temp dir is, you did *not* set it to loadUserProfile

Comment: @AndrewBarber: The article says: "*The answer is pretty straight forward:  turn off loadUserProfile, **or** ACL the temp directory to allow writes.*" Note the "*or*". Thus, according to the article, just setting the ACLs on the temp directory *should* fix the problem, but it doesn't. But yes, the workaround using loadUserProfile is useful, so +1 to the answer (no "accepted answer" yet, since it does not answer the original question -- "why does the write access to C:\Windows\Temp not work even though full permissions are given"). :-)

Comment: Agree with @Heinzi ... although it does not answer the original question here, it does solve the problem, so +1.